# kafka consumer acknowledgment is possible? , from broker to consumer..!

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is it possible to introduce a callback, or something like that in Kafka-**Consumer** side, which will in-turn **guarantees** the message delivered..!

version .10 - kafka-broker, couldn't find anything apart from `auto commit "false"`, and `commitsync` manually, can somebody guide me to achieve it in java-api...

Comment: I cannot follow. Please rephrase your question. Kafka gives you strong delivery guarantees out-of-the box. Not sure what problem you are facing...

Comment: Solved it, by using seeking api of Kafka, for each records, from the broker till it gets saved in any dataSources..

Comment: but I don't know, if it is the best solution, looking for your suggestions on the same..